# Passing parameters to CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I created codepipeline for my stack and during commit on a specific branch, there should be triggered update stack, everything works ok but the problem is with parameters, especially with secret parameters. Here is my question:
1. How can I omit "ugly" JSON string in ParameterOverrides, right now, there is no problem but if I will override more than 30 parameters it will be a long string, can I include JSON file with parameters? If yes, how can I do this?

```
 "ResRootStackCodePipeline": {
  "Type": "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline",
  "DependsOn": [
    "ResRootStackServerI"
  ],
  "Properties": {
    "Name": "AutoProjectCodePipeline",
    "RestartExecutionOnUpdate": "true",
    "RoleArn": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        "",
        [
          "arn:aws:iam::",
          {
            "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
          },
          ":role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "ArtifactStore": {
      "Type": "S3",
      "Location": "bucket-codepipeline-test"
    },
    "Stages": [
      {
        "Name": "APSource",
        "Actions": [
          {
            "Name": "APSourceProcess",
            "ActionTypeId": {
              "Category": "Source",
              "Owner": "ThirdParty",
              "Provider": "GitHub",
              "Version": "1"
            },
            "RunOrder": 1,
            "Configuration": {
              "Branch": "instances-test",
              "OAuthToken": "xxx",
              "Owner": "muume",
              "PollForSourceChanges": "true",
              "Repo": "autoproject-aws-infra"
            },
            "OutputArtifacts": [
              {
                "Name": "APGithubArtifact"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "APDeploy",
        "Actions": [
          {
            "Name": "APUpdateProcess",
            "ActionTypeId": {
              "Category": "Deploy",
              "Owner": "AWS",
              "Provider": "CloudFormation",
              "Version": "1"
            },
            "RunOrder": 1,
            "Configuration": {
              "ActionMode": "CREATE_UPDATE",
              "RoleArn": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:iam::",
                    {
                      "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                    },
                    ":role/CloudFormationRole"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "StackName": {
                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
              },
              "ParameterOverrides": { "Fn::Join": [ "", [
                "{\"ParaNamePrefix\": \"tescik\",\"ParaTemplateURI\": \"https://localhost.xx/\",\"ParaServerInstanceTypeFront\": \"t2.medium\"}"
                ]]},
              "TemplatePath": "APGithubArtifact::instances-test/Stack_Root_I.json",
              "TemplateConfiguration": "APGithubArtifact::instances-test/simple_configuration.json"

            },
            "OutputArtifacts": [],
            "InputArtifacts": [
              {
                "Name": "APGithubArtifact"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

maybe do you see another solution to manage with that problem?

Comment: Is there a way to use !Ref on ParameterOverrides?

Answer (score 1):

Use YAML. It's much better than JSON for CloudFormation. Here's an example of what Parameter Overrides might look like:

```
ParameterOverrides: |-
          {
            "SomeParameterOverride": "xxx",
            "SomeOtherParameterOverride":"yyy"
          }
```

You can easily convert your existing JSON to YAML using the Cloudformation designer or a site like this: https://www.json2yaml.com/

FYI: YAML also allows for comments and easy referencing of other resources and parameters in the template.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html):

> We recommend that you use the template configuration file to specify most of your parameter values. Use parameter overrides to specify dynamic parameter values only. Dynamic parameters are unknown until you run the pipeline.

Keep in mind that there is a 1KB limit on the size of parameter overrides too.